# panda qcut into 10 buckets. but later can't sort it properly

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to quantile qcut on a numeric variable and plot is's relationship with a variable price.

```
df3['quantile_house_size'] = pd.qcut(df3['house_size'], q=10, precision=0)
df3['quantile_house_size'].value_counts()

quantile_house_size 
(1223.0, 1400.0]     31682
(2188.0, 2650.0]     31356
(2650.0, 3500.0]     31315
(1044.0, 1223.0]     31278
(307.0, 815.0]       31264
(815.0, 1044.0]      31227
(1604.0, 1867.0]     31223
(1867.0, 2188.0]     31218
(3500.0, 70626.0]    31033
(1400.0, 1604.0]     30827
Name: count, dtype: int64

quantile_grouped = df3.groupby(df3.quantile_house_size.astype(str))['price'].mean()
sorted_s_index_desc = quantile_grouped.sort_index(ascending=True)
sorted_s_index_desc

quantile_house_size
(1044.0, 1223.0]     5.103364e+05
(1223.0, 1400.0]     5.406730e+05
(1400.0, 1604.0]     5.604197e+05
(1604.0, 1867.0]     6.326445e+05
(1867.0, 2188.0]     7.138814e+05
(2188.0, 2650.0]     9.642463e+05
(2650.0, 3500.0]     1.050743e+06
(307.0, 815.0]       5.113049e+05
(3500.0, 70626.0]    2.583585e+06
(815.0, 1044.0]      4.676279e+05
nan                  7.919342e+05
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

The (815.0, 1044.0],(1044.0, 1223.0] are not sorted properly.
I don't want to go down the route of reset_index. And I want to keep the value range for each bin as well, which I don't want to assign a label [0-9] at the qcut stage. Is there any other quick solution for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Regardless of the fact that you need to create examples to ask questions, code of `astype(str)` section make your alignment state. Because of string, it is sorted alphabetically, not by the size of the number.

Comment: why do you need to convert to string for groupby? `df3.groupby('quantile_hose_size').mean()` works just fine, and you get to sort the intervals as expected.